# Giant Pufferfish skin pattern―how could that be generated

Tags: tiling, tessellations

I just started my investigations about tesselations and tilings for some very special kind of design Project. I came over that image:

[image: Giant Pufferfish Skin Pattern]

It shows a part of the Giant Pufferfish's skin and I am very curious about to find out how this pattern could be generated, so that it can be continued infinite in x- and y-direction, without self-repeating.

However I am not a mathematician and quite new to this Topic, so I appreciate any Kind of Help or Hint that gives me some guidance.

Thanks in ahead!

Comment: While this isn't quite the same (your pattern has plenty of the yellow pieces disconnected from the main group), you might consider the example [on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_formation#Computer_graphics). If you could implement or find blur/sharpen algorithms on a torus (i.e, they act as if the edges of the image are connected to each other pac-man style) then the result should automatically be a tessellation. I think the major issue would be actually generating the pattern itself.

Comment: [You should watch this.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN8tVldm6QY)

Comment: @Raskolnikov I watched the video and searched along for Turing patterns, because that is indeed a very good approach, nearly exactly what I am looking for. Do you probably have some more resources for that?

Comment: You could start with the [original paper of Turing](http://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf) and maybe look up the papers of [professor Philip Maini](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/maini/).

Comment: @Raskolnikov Thanks for that, I will have a look at it.

Comment: @RobertMastragostino on wikipedia page you postet, there was a video a the top right, I try to make something kind of animation exactly like that. Right now I just found a very cool website for that subject: http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.0030212

Answer (score 1):

The first mathematician I know to tackle the problem of pattern formation in chemical processes and biological morphogenesis was Alan Turing in his seminal paper "[The Chemical Basis of Morphogenesis](http://www.dna.caltech.edu/courses/cs191/paperscs191/turing.pdf)". As you'll notice, it is not quite what you had in mind. But if you delve into it more deeply you might find things analogous to tesselations. I just doubt that tesselations are really the way to go when describing this type of patterns.

Here's a [nice video lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN8tVldm6QY) by [professor Philip Maini](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/maini/) about that topic.